# Latex - color in verbatim environment: commandchars is printed

Tags: latex

I would like to use some colors in my verbatim environment. According to the solutions I found I use following packages:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

My verbatim env. looks like follows:

```
\begin{verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
some stuff...
\textcolor{blue}{some colored stuff}
\end{verbatim}
```

My problem is that the verbatim env. starts immediately after the closing verbatim bracket "}" so that "[commandchars=\{}]" is printed as well as "some stuff" and the line after. How can I fix that?

Comment: Did nobody have the same problem? I still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the solution was simple: You have to use a capital "V" for Verbatim.